# Not able to upload photo by automotion on tumblr platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation

[image]PFB my code for Autopost on Tumblr please correct my 28 no. line

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui
import time


email = "Email"
passwd = "Password"


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

driver.get("https://www.tumblr.com/login")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="base-container"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div/form/input')
pyautogui.typewrite(email)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press("Enter")
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.typewrite(passwd)
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.press("Enter")
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="base-container"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/main/div[3]/ul/li[2]/button/span').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="row-0"]/div/div/div[1]/button[1]/span/input').click()
time.sleep(5)
```

error in below line -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="row-0"]/div/div/div[1]/button[1]/span/input').click()
```

maybe iframe is not defined, please anyone give me your ideas.

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="row-0"]/div/div/div[1]/button[1]/span/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)

Comment: @RamDayal : Please post the relevant HTML of the input element along with parent tag.

Comment: Can you try this out ?
`img_upload = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file'][@name='photo']")` `img_upload.send_keys("C:\\Users\\Pictures\\Logo.jpg")`

Comment: @Madhan : I am facing below error -selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='file'][@name='photo']"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)

Comment: @Kunduk: Please check I uploaded HTML code.

Comment: @RamDayal : Try following `xpath`  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@role='button' and @type='file']")

Comment: @Kunduk: I am facing the below error - selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@role='button' and @type='file']"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)    According to my knowledge iframe is available for this button. So maybe first try to driver switch to iframe

Comment: @RamDayal : Can you check the parent node if there any `iframe` or `shadow-root` element.

Comment: Are you using my snippet after clicking on the `Photo` button ?

Comment: @Madhan: I used but again I received an error which is I already have sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see the problem is with the XPATH of the element where you upload the file.

Try something like this:

```
# First make sure to import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

upload = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file'])))

upload.send_keys("/path/to/your/image")
```

Also, I'd recommend doing the `WebDriverWait` instead of doing `time.sleep()` so the program is more consistent with the timing rather than just waiting a specific amount of time, in case it takes longer than expected to load.

Comment: I am facing below error -   File "C:\Users\Ram\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Auto Post\test.py", line 33, in <module>
    upload = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")))
  File "C:\Users\Ram\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Auto Post\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: The only option left from what I see is that the elements are inside an iframe and you would need to switch to that iframe. From the HTML that you posted I don't see any but you need to provide more information in order to know that,